# Half of Laravel Migrations Run

Tags: laravel-4, migration

I've got a problem when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Only four of my sixteen migrations get run for some reason. No errors are spit out, and I checked, all three of the databases are there. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Results of -vvv is not different than no -v or -v.

Comment: Try running mugrate with the verbose switch and see what are the output on the terminal  `php artisan migrate -v`

Comment: what do you mean "all three of the databases are there"?

Comment: Not all of the schemas are related to the same databases. There are three databases, I use Schema::connection('main')->create('users'....